# Is [] a valid type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
  function stringToArray(s: string|[]): [] {
    return typeof s === 'string' ? JSON.parse(s.replace(/'/g, '"')) : s;
  }
```

It works as intended and I don't have any type warnings with it. However I was wondering if [] is a valid type ? Is it the same as any[] ?

Comment: It is valid and represents empty array/tuple, but doesn't make sense in most cases. It is not the same as `any[]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGBtAujAvGgjOgKCA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's absolutely valid. `[]` is type of empty [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-3.html#tuple-types).

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3An1w)

Answer (score 0):

`any[]` and `[]` both are completely different.

`[]` represent empty array and `any[]` represent array of any type.

you can not push any value to the type `[]` rather than use strict mode, for that you have to mention type in square braces like `[string], [number], [{name: string}]`